# How to use string.replace() with JSON strings?

Tags: javascript, json, replace

I have a backend that's sending invalid JSON strings. It escapes vertical tabs as \v which is not valid in JSON and ends up being rejected by the parser.

I am trying to remedy the problem in the frontend JSON decoder:

```js
function fromJson(json) {
  if(typeof json === "string") {
    var jsonString = json.replace(/\v/g, "\u000B");
    return JSON.parse(jsonString)
  }
  else {
    return json
  }
}
```

Expected output: new string with all instances of \v replaced with the unicode line tabulation.

Actual output:

> JSON.parse: SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position...

Comment: Kindly post your JSON input. It seems String replace method is affecting the structure of your JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript interprets `\` characters as [special characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-backslash) in regular expressions. It expects the character after the `\` to have a special meaning, but `v` isn't one of the special characters. Hence the exception `Unexpected token v in JSON`.

To fix your issue you need to escape the `\` character in your regex with another `\`, e.g. `json.replace(/\\v/g, "\u000B");`

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick after also correctly escaping the unicode escape character.